# Average temperature by day of year with SQLite DDB

Tags: sqlite, average, temperature

I'm looking for a good solution to show the average temperature day by day of the year from a SQLite Database.

In my database, to be sample, I have a date column and a temp column, for each day since 5 years like that.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH6YH.png)

I would like to get, for each day of the year, the average temperature from my database.
I found the request to calculate the average for one day, but I don't how can I do like that for each day

```
SELECT avg(min) FROM historique WHERE strftime('%m-%d', date )= "04-01";
```

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT strftime('%m-%d', date) day, avg(min) 
FROM historique 
GROUP BY day
```

Comment: Oh great ! Thank you for your help !